# Incrementing char value (more than one letter)

Tags: c++, string, char, increment, strstr

I am confronted with the following code:

```
int get_config(const char *key, char *value) {

FILE *fp = NULL;
char s[100];
char *ret1 = NULL;
char *ret2 = NULL;

fp = fopen(CONFIG_FILE_PATH, "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    perror(CONFIG_FILE_PATH);
    return FALSE;
}

while (fgets(s, 100, fp) != NULL) {
    //printf("line=%s", s);
    ret1 = strstr(s, key);
    if (ret1 != NULL) {

        ret1 = strstr(s, "=");
        if (ret1 != NULL) {
            ret1++;
            ret2 = strstr(s, "\n");

            strncpy(value, ret1, ret2 - ret1);
            //printf("ret1=%p ret2=%p\n", ret1,ret2);
            value[ret2 - ret1] = 0x0;

            printf("config key=%s value=%s\n", key, value);

            fclose(fp);
            fp = NULL;
            ret1 = NULL;
            ret2 = NULL;

            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

I struggle to understand what `ret1++` does. If I understood the `strstr()` correctly, after `ret1 = strstr(s, "=");` ret1 will contain all everything following the = sign within s.

Lets assume this not a number, but a word "value", resulting in `ret1 = value` What does this mean for `ret1++`?
Maybe my assumption of the CONFIG_FILE_PATH is wrong, and a number always follows the equal sign.

Sidenote:
*I just wished, I knew what CONFIG_FILE_PATH looks like. But as `#define CONFIG_FILE_PATH "/etc/config/duvs.conf"` But this path is probably located on the device, this program is written for... :/*

Comment: What are you talking about? `ret1` points either to the C-string following `=` (possibly the empty string) or equals to `NULL`.

Comment: Mybe I am confused due to this description here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

In the example provided below, `ret` equals `Point` which led me to assume, that in my case `ret1` also equals to a string. Thus making me not understand, how `ret1++` makes any sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

`ret1` is a  pointer.

I supposer your variable `s` is "`dir=/my/path`".

The value *points* to the character. In your example, `strstr(s, "=");` returns NULL if the "=" has not been found or its pointer inside the string. Meaning `ret1` contains a string with the rest of the text *including* the "=" (`=/my/path` in my example). By incrementing of 1 character (`ret++`), the pointer points now to the same string one character after: `/my/path`.

This is the basics of C code where pointers are used because strings are not really part of the language but just memory data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am really inexperienced  when it comes to pointers. Thus didn`t understand the idea of `ret1++` = pointing to the next character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

> After `ret1 = strstr(s, "=");` ret1 will contain all everything
>   following the = sign within s.

You are right.
Let's assume `s` is the string `enable=false\n`.
After `ret1` is incremented with `ret1++`, it points to the character `f`.
After the statement `ret2 = strstr(s, "\n");`, the pointer `ret2` points to the character `\n`.

`ret2 - ret1` equals 5 which is the length of the substring `false`. For pointer arithmetic, [this article](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) may help you.

After `strncpy(value, ret1, ret2 - ret1);`, the content of `value` is the string `false`.

EDIT:
The configuration file specified with `CONFIG_FILE_PATH` may look like this:

```
timeout=30
enable=false
priority=5
log=/var/log/mylogfile
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this visual example. One of my problems was, not being able to imagine how s (and therefore CONFIG_FILE_PATH) looks like, as I am  really inexperienced programmer.

Comment: @user3554329 I think it is a key-value based configuration file.  Its content may like this: `key=value`. This is an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file#MS-DOS